# How to resize csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Say I have a csv file with 1000+ rows. I want to remove the last however many rows so I have a csv file of exactly 1000 rows. Also, is there a quick way to do this using python (maybe pandas) as I have a set of 2000+ csv files.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Copy the first 1000 rows into memory (if you can) and make a new CSV file to dump them into

Comment: The `split` command on any Unix-like system lets you split a file into chunks of specific sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the nrows option in pandas like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filename, nrows=1000)
```

This will keep only the first 1000 rows of the csv files.
If you have multiple csv files, you can iterate over them using a for loop

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Great! If it helps, please mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: This is probably a better approach instead of reading the full file and then slicing as it will not read all the data but only 1000 rows.

Comment: Yep, this is more efficient and then I can simply df.to_csv() because I require a new file.

Comment: Does the header count in the 1000 rows?

Comment: No, the header will be excluded in this method

Comment: Okay, that's fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')

dfnew = df.head(1000)

dfnew.to_csv('newfilename.csv')
```

will give you the first 1000 rows

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!